# How can you cache a WCF client object in httpsession?

Tags: c#, wcf

I am writing a middleware web service that invoke other web services. They each have session based data, so for the life of the session I would like to use the same client to get the proper results

I tried caching a WCF client object in httpsession. This led to a error indicating that this object is not serializable. Is there another way I can save this client object? I can't use a singleton as each session needs to have different connections so data is not confused.

Comment: Did you try to mark your object with `[Serializable]` attribute?

Comment: I thought you can only use [Serializable] on a class, not on an object?

Comment: that's what i meant, object is instance of class, mark class with attribute